# Simple Service Discovery on linux

Tags: c++, ssdp

I am trying to implement some kind of service discovery in my network. In particular i want my linux powered devices to be disvored by an Android application. I came across [ssdp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) and this seems to be suitable for my task. I was looking for some ssdp libraries for c++ but did not found any.
Do i have to implement it on my own? if so, can you give a brief overview on how this can be done? Or is it just about sending NOTIFY messages over UDP, which can be done without a library!

regards

Answer (score 3):

Unless using a C library is against your religion, you could use GSSDP: it's a well tested SSDP implementation (it is a part of the [GUPnP](https://wiki.gnome.org/GUPnP/) stack) that only depends on glib, gobject and libsoup. See [reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gssdp/unstable/) and [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gssdp/).

Answer (score 0):

The wiki article you linked to mentions UPnP as a successor to SSDP. Perhaps libupnp has what you need? http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually, i dont News the whole upnp stack, but just a mechanism for easy discovery of my devices

Comment: You have that backwards. SSDP is the successor (and superset) to UPnP.